# Como fazer uma função recursiva para somar todos os valores de uma lista em Elixir

Tags: elixir

Eu gostaria de uma função que, recebendo como parametro uma lista, me retorne o somátório da lista. Algo como:

```
iex(0)> Recursive.sumAll([1, 3, 5]) 
# => 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir possui uma maneira bem inteligente de lidar com funções recursivas, pelo fato de as listas por padrão já serem **encadeadas** ou **linkadas**.

### Head and Tail (cabeça e cauda)

Em Elixir as listas podem ser separadas em duas partes, head(cabeça) e tail(cauda). Onde a cabeça é o primeiro elemento da lista e a cauda é todos os outros elementos subsequentes.

Representação normal de uma lista:

```
iex(0)> a = [1, 2]
```

Representação head and tail:

```
iex(1)> a = [1 | [2]]
```

Tanto que se verficarmos a equivalência com um operador `==` veremos que são maneiras diferentes de representar a mesma coisa.

```
iex(0)> [1, 2] === [1 | [2]]
true
```

> Importante dizer que essa regra vale mesmo para as listas que possuem apenas um elemento. Onde o Head é o único elemento e uma lista vazia é o tail: `iex(2)> [1] == [1 | []] # => true`

Com esse conhecimento, fica fácil para nós montarmos nosso método de recursão:

```
defmodule Recursive do
    # Definimos a condicional limitante da nossa função
    def sumAll([]), do: 0
    # Imprementamos a recursão de fato
    def sumAll([head | tail]), do: head + sumAll(tail)
end
```

O nosso método irá percorrer toda a lista e somar o head anterior com o head do tail, até que cheguemos a uma lista vazia:

```
iex(9)> Recursive.sumAll([1,1,1])
3
```